# Copy a range and paste only rows with values & images into another sheet at the next blank row in the google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I need your help to copy and paste script above. There are variable rows of data in the range of B12:W44. There might be 2 or 20 rows of data. If there are 2 rows of data, there are 2 rows with values and 31 blank rows in the target range after I run the code. How to copy and paste only cells with data? So much blank rows in the target range :((

```
function Movedata3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("INVOICE");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("HISTORICAL SALES");
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("B12:W44");
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- In your situation, the range of "B12:W44" of the source sheet has multiple empty rows. About the empty row, in this case, all columns from "B" to "W" are empty cells. And, the row includes the values and the images.
- By removing the empty rows, you want to copy only the values and the images to the last row of the destination sheet.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

**In this modification, Sheets API is used. So, before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).**

```js
function Movedata3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("INVOICE");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("HISTORICAL SALES");
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("B12:W44");
  var srcSheetId = srcSheet.getSheetId();
  var dstSheetId = dstSheet.getSheetId();
  var srcStartRow = srcRange.getRow();
  var srcStartCol = srcRange.getColumn();
  var srcEndCol = srcStartCol + srcRange.getNumColumns();
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  var dstStartRow = dstRange.getRow();
  var requests = srcRange.getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    if (r.join("") != "") {
      ar.push({ copyPaste: { source: { sheetId: srcSheetId, startRowIndex: i + srcStartRow - 1, endRowIndex: i + srcStartRow, startColumnIndex: srcStartCol - 1, endColumnIndex: srcEndCol }, destination: { sheetId: dstSheetId, startRowIndex: dstStartRow + ar.length - 1, endRowIndex: dstStartRow + ar.length }, pasteType: "PASTE_VALUES" } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this modification, the rows except for the empty rows are retrieved from "B12:W44" in the source sheet. And, those rows are copied to the destination sheet.
- When Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used, each row is copied using a loop. In this case, I thought that the process cost will become high. So, in this answer, I proposed to use Sheets API.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [CopyPasteRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#copypasterequest)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your modified script's idea is exactly what I want. But I don't know about the Google sheet's API and I can't still make it work. I enabled Google sheet's  API. After I run the script, they said "Sheets is not defined". Are there somehow any replaces which describes sheet id or anything else? I looked through your suggested references and don't get what I need to do. Please, help me. :))

Comment: @Bella Curt Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand what you did from `I enabled Google sheet's API.`. However, about the error of `Sheets is not defined`, it is considered that Sheets API is not enabled yet. So, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) I think that when Sheets API is correctly enabled, the script works.

Comment: thanks for your helping. I enabled the Google Sheet's API but it doesn't work and shows error like "Sheets is not defined" too. How am I supposed to do?

Comment: @Bella Curt Thank you for replying. About `I enabled the Google Sheet's API but it doesn't work and shows error like "Sheets is not defined" too. How am I supposed to do? –`, in this case, I think that Sheets API is not enabled yet. So, please confirm it again. Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? For example, if you have enabled Sheets API at another Google Apps Script project, such an error occurs. Please be careful about this. I think that when Sheets API is correctly enabled, the script works.

Comment: @Bella Curt As one more my worry, in this case, please enable Sheets API at the script editor of Google Apps Script project that you copied and pasted my proposed script. Even when you did this, when the same issue occurs, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.